# SQL LEFT JOIN multiple tables including link to 1 table for each join

Tags: sql, left-join

For the sake of explaining my problem lets say I am building cars. In my DB a car is made out of parts (engine, chassis, wheel). Each part has a physical location (part_location from the table locations) which is linked via (part_location = location_id).

In my case, there will be only 1 of each part, each part is unique

In my query I am trying to assembly my cars in a query, including the city and country of each part (not the id)

The beginning of my query:

```
SELECT car_name, car_type, engine_name, engine_type, chassis_name, chassis_type, wheel_name, wheel_type
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN engines ON car_id = engine_car_id
LEFT JOIN chassis ON car_id = chassis_car_id 
LEFT JOIN wheels ON car_id = wheel_car_id
```

How can I include the location of each part (e.g. car_city, car_country; an alias for each part from location_city, location_country)?

My tables are set up as follows:

```
Table cars
    car_id
    car_name
    car_type

Table engines (same for chassis, wheels)
    engine_id
    engine_name
    engine_type
    engine_car_id
    engine_location_id

Table locations
    location_id
    location_city
    location_country
```

Comment: Provide the structure of your both the tables

Comment: I have now done so in my original post

Comment: Post with you data and how your result should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea behind your query is correct.  You should write it with explicit aliases, so I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT c.car_name, c.car_type, e.engine_name, e.engine_type, 
       ch.chassis_name, ch.chassis_type,
       w.wheel_name, w.wheel_type,
       el.city as engine_city
FROM cars c LEFT JOIN
     engines e
     ON e.car_id = c.engine_id LEFT JOIN
     chassis ch
     ON ch.car_id = c.chassis_id LEFT JOIN
     wheels w
     ON w.wheel_car_id = c.car_id LEFT JOIN
     locations el
     ON el.location_id = e.location_id
```

However, without the table layouts or sample data, this is just a guess.

Comment: The query I show works as expected. I gets all the separate parts into 1 car. I just can't figure out how to properly add the location information. I edited my original post with the table structure

Comment: @Jelmer . . . First, your original query would *not* have worked correctly, but you edited it after I answered.  Second, I just modified the answer to show how you can put the engine location information in.  You can add an additional join for each element where you want the location.